# Relation between Authorization middleware and filter Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, filter, authorization, middleware

I was watching tutorial about Asp .net core and I was wondering the difference between filters and middleware and after some research I found the answer of my question that middleware pipeline is proceed before  filter pipeline. but I face with strange situation!
when I use [Authorize] before any action method as it is a filter what is the purpose of using authentication and authorization middleware? because the filter is executed after middlewares.

I mean the main question is that what is the purpose of using authentication and authorization middlerware and what is the flow of processing Request when we use [Authorize] before any action method?

Comment: If your pipeline includes `UseMvc`, the `[Authorize]` attributes will be considered even if `UseAuthorization` is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the authorization filter is part of the authorization middleware's responsibilities. It will not work if the authorization middleware is missing and an exception will be thrown at runtime.

What happens is whenever an HTTP request comes, it will go through the middleware pipeline. The authentication middleware will work on authenticating the user (that has sent the request) using a previously configured authentication scheme such as cookie or token. The authorization middleware then will work on comparing the claims of the user, that are existing inside the provided token or cookie, with the security requirements that are specified through the [Authorize] attribute. If the authorization failed, the HTTP request will be filtered out and the access to the requested action method will be prevented.

This is a summary about how things work, hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have a misunderstanding of the concepts.

Middleware is piece of code that's placed into an app pipeline to handle requests and responses.

Filter is not a middleware, it is piece of code that can be run before or after specific  stages in `UseEndpoints` middleware (razor pages or controllers). you can think of filters as a semi-Middleware that is placed in a smaller pipeline handling endpoints.

I recommend you refer to [Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and [Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for more information.

Comment: i do not understand why was this downvoted. In my opinion, it includes very useful links that explain the flow.